# How to compose it?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Target: build opencv docker

Dockerfile creation:

```
From Ubuntu14.04
```

or

```
From Python3.7
```

Which to choose and why?

I was trying to write dockerfile from scratch without copy paste from others dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

I would usually pick the highest-level [Docker Hub library image](https://docs.docker.com/samples/#library-references) that matches what I need.  It's also worth searching the https://hub.docker.com/ search box which will often [find relevant things](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=opencv&type=image), though of rather varied ownership and maintenance levels.

The official Docker Hub images tend to have thought through a lot of issues around persistence and configuration and first-time setup.  Compare "I'll just `apt-get install mysql-server`" with all of the parts that go into [the official `mysql` image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/master/8.0); just importing that real-world experience and reusing it can save you some trouble.

I'd consider building my own from an OS base like `ubuntu:16.04` if:

- There is a requirement that Docker images must be built from some specific distribution base ("my job requires everything to be built off of CentOS so I need a CentOS-based MySQL image")
- I need a combination of software versions or patches that the Docker Hub image no longer supports (`jruby:9.1.16.0` is no longer being built, so if I need OS updates, I need to build my own base image)
- I need an especially exotic set of build options for whatever reason ("I have a C extension that only works if the interpreter is specifically built with UTF-16 Unicode support")
- I need or want very detailed control over what version(s) of software are embedded; for example if it's something Java-based where there's a JVM version and a runtime version and an application version that all could matter

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should choose `From Python3.7`.

Since you are writing a dockerfile for `opencv` which is an open source computer vision and machine learning software library so you may require python also in your container. 
Now if you use `From Ubuntu14.04` you may need to add python also in the dockerfile whereas with `From Python3.7` that will become redundant and will also make the dockerfile a bit shorter.

Comment: they use alpine linux as the base not ubuntu , however, your answer is good, but miss the edge case.